# Is there an easier way to adjust the size of an SVG?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am looking to cut the image of the SVG in half. The SVG is the lighter wave at the bottom of the circle. It is currently too high, and I need to reduce the size by about half. I placed the SVG in a container of its own, but modifying the size of the container isn't exactly modifying the size of the image in ways I would expect. Any suggestion are appreciated.

```dart
    return Container(
      decoration: bubbleBoxDecoration,
      height: bubbleDiameter.toDouble(),
      width: bubbleDiameter.toDouble(),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Upper Body',
                  style: labelTextStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  '45',
                  style: weightTextStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  'lbs',
                  style: unitTextStyle,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: bubbleDiameter.toDouble(),
            width: bubbleDiameter.toDouble(),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              assetName,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Image example]

Comment: did you tried: `SvgPicture.asset(
              assetName,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              width: 100,
              height: 100
            ),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trick the UI while using `Stack` and make the image size the way you want. You need to resize the image and align properly. The only reason your code-snippet is not reflecting the size because `Stack` child require a positional widget like `Positioned` / `Align` to reflect custom size.

```
 Positioned(
            bottom: -100,// bubbleDiameter.toDouble() the way you like to align
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              assetName,
            height: bubbleDiameter.toDouble() * 2,
            width: bubbleDiameter.toDouble() *2,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the `fit` parameter. Also, since you want to cut off the bottom and see the top, use `Alignment.topCenter`.

```
Container(
  height: bubbleDiameter.toDouble() / 2,
  width: bubbleDiameter.toDouble(),
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
    assetName,
    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify an asset image in flutter. even if you can, it won't be ideal, because it's an asset, you can remove , edit and add it back, rather than modifying the asset every time you run your app.